# Problema con edicion en laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un modulo para editar, el cual funciona muy bien, muestro a continuación el controlador y la vista.

```html
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
    {
       
            $request->user()->authorizeRoles(['admin','referido']);
            $usuarios=usuarios::find($id);
            return view('usuario.edit',compact('usuarios'));
    

    }
```

la vista.

```html
@extends('layouts.layout')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
 <section class="content">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

   @if(Session::has('success'))
   <div class="alert alert-info">
    {{Session::get('success')}}
   </div>
   @endif
 
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title">Nuevo usuario</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">     
     <div class="table-container">

      <form method="POST" action="{{ route('usuario.update',$usuarios->id) }}"  role="form">
       {{ csrf_field() }}
       <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">



                              <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group">
          <input type="number" name="id" id="id" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="id" value="{{{ $usuarios->id }}}" readonly="readonly" style="visibility:hidden">
         </div>
        </div>
      
                          </div>


       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('nombre') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
          <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{$usuarios->nombre}}">
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('apellido') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
          <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{$usuarios->apellido}}">
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>


                            <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
             <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('telefonos') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <input type="number" name="telefonos" id="telefonos" min="1111111" max="9999999999" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{$usuarios->telefonos}}">
               @if ($errors->has('telefonos'))
                                         <span class="help-block">
                                             <strong>{{ $errors->first('telefono') }}</strong>
                                         </span>
                                        @endif
           </div>
        </div>
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('cedula') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
          <input type="number" name="cedula" id="cedula" min="1111111" max="9999999999" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{$usuarios->cedula}}">
             @if ($errors->has('cedula'))
                                              <span class="help-block">
                                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('cedula') }}</strong>
                                              </span>
                                           @endif
          </div>
          </div>
                               </div>


                            <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="barrio" id="barrio" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{$usuarios->barrio}}">
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="lugar_votacion" id="lugar_votacion" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{$usuarios->lugar_votacion}}">
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="mesa_votacion" id="mesa_votacion" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{$usuarios->mesa_votacion}}">
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{$usuarios->email}}">
          @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                              <span class="help-block">
                                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                              </span>
                                           @endif
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>


                           <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group"> 

                                        <select name="ciudad" id="ciudad" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{$usuarios->ciudad}}">
                                           <option value="{{$usuarios->ciudad}}">{{$usuarios->ciudad}}</option>
                                           <option value="Pereira">Pereira</option>
                                           <option value="Apía">Apía</option>
                                           <option value="Balboa">Balboa</option>
                                           <option value="Belén de Umbría">Belén de Umbría</option>
                                           <option value="Dosquebradas">Dosquebradas</option>
                                           <option value="Guática">Guática</option>
                                           <option value="La Celia">La Celia</option>
                                           <option value="La Virginia">La Virginia</option>
                                           <option value="Marsella">Marsella</option>
                                           <option value="Mistrató">Mistrató</option>
                                           <option value="Pueblo Rico">Pueblo Rico</option>
                                           <option value="Quinchía">Quinchía</option>
                                           <option value="Santa Rosa de Cabal">Santa Rosa de Cabal</option>
                                           <option value="Santuario">Santuario</option>
                                        </select>

         </div>
        </div>
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{$usuarios->direccion}}">
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="row">
 
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
         <input type="submit"  value="Actualizar" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
        </div> 
 
       </div>
      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
 
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 @endsection
```

El problema viene cuando hago el siguiente cambio en el controlador.

```html
  public function edit(Request $request, $id)
    {
       
        
            $request->user()->authorizeRoles(['admin','referido']);
            $filtro = \Auth::user()->id;
            $usuarios=usuarios::where('id',$id)->where('user_id',$filtro)->get();
            return view('usuario.edit',compact('usuarios'));
    

    }
```

Lo único que quiero lograr es que quien inicie sesión pueda ver los registros de el y no de otro, la consulta esta bien, el problema esta es en la vista, por que me aparece este error.

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View:
>   C:\laragon\www\stsroles\resources\views\Usuario\edit.blade.php)

No se por que, como puedo adaptar esto, para que la vista lea la información así como se pasa con find()?

Comment: El problema no es de la vista, es de la lógica con la que se aborda el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error esta en el get() ya que devuelve un array de objetos, deberías probar con first() el cual si devuelve un solo objeto.

```
$usuarios=usuarios::where('id',$id)->where('user_id',$filtro)->first();
```

No es la solución al problema de logica pero si al de implementación.

Comment: Esa consulta no le veo logica, si ya vamos a obtener un usuario por su id; el cual solo nos debe devolver un registro, el usar first esta de más

Comment: Gracias nashvent, efectivamente era el error.

Comment: Esta respuesta contiene muchos errores y puede confundir a futuros visitantes.

Comment: Hize una aclaración en la respuesta para evitar la confusión.

Comment: cuando usas first() en laravel te devuelve el objeto directamente, con get() obtienes un array que contiene los objetos aunque sea solo un registro.

Answer (score 1):

**La respuesta aceptada resuelve lo planteado, pero no es la solución al problema de lógica que tiene el OP.**

No hay mucha lógica al hacer una comprobación de esta manera en el controlador, debería estar ANTES de llegar ahí, y generar un mensaje, ¿por qué?

Las razones son muy sencillas:

- No debería ser responsabilidad del controlador verificar si tiene permiso o no de edición.
- No se debe realizar una supuesta revisión de permisos obteniendo el modelo y no realizando una comparación hasta llegar a la vista (tampoco es responsabilidad de la vista esta lógica).

---

Soluciones adecuadas en mi opinión:

- Aprovechar las *policies* de Laravel.
- Utilizar los *middleware* de Laravel, realmente funcionan muy bien para hacer comprobaciones sencillas si no se desea abordar la posible complejidad de las *policies*.
- Utilizar *Model Binding* para convertir de antemano el id a su respectivo modelo, podríamos decir que es la norma Laravel para estos casos de utilizar modelos conocidos en un controlador.

Comment: Gracias Shaz, veo que es una buena metodologia, aunque creo que esto me llevara un tiempo aprenderlo a dominar.

Comment: La idea de las preguntas que se realizan en StackOverflow es que las personas que vengan después entiendan qué es lo mejor que se puede hacer, no que tengan como referencia un montón de respuestas que promueven malas prácticas, por favor ténlo en cuenta, pues lo veo constantemente en las preguntas que realizas y en las respuestas que aceptas.

Comment: tienes razon.... es mi primer proyecto y soy conciente de eso.. para futuros proyecto la idea es hacerlo con las mejoras correctas.. buenas practicas como dices.